# 2m FM: where do I actually QSY to after establishing contact on 145.500?

Tags: fm, 2m-band, united-kingdom, etiquette, simplex

I am new to amateur VHF, coming from HF and marine.

Online advice says after establishing contact on 145.500 then QSY. What is the range of channels/frequencies most folks use?  ie that they are likely to have programmed in.

The band plan shows the *extent* of FM voice but not the  traditional/best practice/expected actual frequencies. Given that many rigs are keypad channelized my choosing an unexpected QSY destination wouldn't be helpful.

Comment: Frequency usage varies by region.  You need to tell us what country you are in so someone can provide an answer.

Comment: Oops, wa9zzz. I am in UK

Answer (score 4):

[According to this, the current UK band plan](https://hamradiosouthernrepeaters.co.uk/images/PDF/Simplex_Channel_Frequency.pdf) has FM and DV simplex use at 145.200-145.5935, channelized in 12.5 kHz steps. If you hear loud garbling on a particular channel, it's likely a DV transmission that's not compatible with your rig, so just move along to another channel.

- channel V16 is 145.200
- channel V17 is 145.2125
- channel V18 is 145.225
- ... and so on.

Also, anyone participating on the 145.500 simplex calling freq is likely to have direct tune capability for QSY purposes, but you can always solicit a convenient frequency from your QSO partner.

Welcome to the hobby!!